# ArcGIS ModelBuilder output data from collect values as table or csv

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder

[image]

I have 90 point shapefiles. I would like to export the largest value of one of the fields in the attribute table. I have sorted the field so that the largest number is at the top. I have also added in another field, which is the name of the shapefile so I can export both fields and still know the name of the file.

I am now trying to use 'Get Field Value', 'Collect Values' and an array of tools to get the data into a table or csv or similar which I can work with. see image: I don't have to do both at the same time, I just want to be sure which number comes from which file.

I am not great with Python so if this is possible within ModelBuilder can you help?

Comment: I wouldn’t rely on pre-sorting a table - it may work sometimes but not others. If you want to get the maximum value then you should explicitly do so. Eg, use Summary Statistics with Maximum for the value field and First for the filename field.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting this to work by using two models, which could probably be one but it worked:

1. feature iterator to Summary Statisticstables
2. Table iterator to collect values to Merge tables